# How to step through this evaluation?

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I would like to see how the value of a square root is iteratively improved. For example on the following:

```
#lang sicp
(define (square x) (* x x))
(define (average x y) (/ (+ x y) 2))
(define (improve guess x) (average guess (/ x guess)))
(define (good-enough? guess x) (< (abs (- (square guess) x)) 0.001 ))
(define (sqrt-iter guess x) (if (good-enough? guess x) guess (sqrt-iter (improve guess x) x)))
(define (sqrt x) (sqrt-iter 1.0 x))
(sqrt 2)
```

It gets values such as the following:

```
1 1
2 1.5
3 1.4166666666666665
4 1.4142156862745097
```

As an example of what I want to show, in Javascript I would do something like:

```
const sqrt_iter = (guess, x) => {
    console.log(count++, guess);
    return good_enough(guess, x) ? guess : sqrt_iter(improve(guess, x), x);
}
const sqrt = x => sqrt_iter(1.0, x);
```

How could I print or trace these intermediate values in DrRacket/SICP? I tried doing `(trace sqrt)` but it said not found.

Comment: Doesn't DrRacket have a built-in debugger?

Comment: @ScottHunter -- sure, but how would you use it on the above? The debugging just does one step and evaluates `(sqrt 2)` to 1.4.

Comment: Did you set any breakpoints?  Did you start the program with Debug instead of Run?

Comment: DrRacket debugger docs: https://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/debugger.html?msclkid=95da0250cfc911ec997d06ba851d1a08

Comment: @ScottHunter thanks -- how do I add a breakpoint?

Comment: Read the docs: https://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/debugger.html#%28part._.Definitions_.Window_.Actions%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure Racket has some fancy trace facility.  But there's a famous quote (due I think to John Foderaro):

> Lisp [for which read Racket] is the *programmable* programming language.

What this means is: if there's no tracing facility, or you are too lazy to make one, you can just write one.

Here is a rudimentary one I wrote in five minutes:

```
#lang racket

(provide define/traced)

(define trace-depths (make-parameter 0))

(define (spaces n)
  (make-string n #\ ))

(define-syntax define/traced
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ (name arg ...) form ...)
     (define/traced name (λ (arg ...) form ...))]
    [(_ (name . args) form ...)
     (define/traced name (λ args form ...))]
    [(_ name function)
     (define name
       (λ args
         (let* ([depth (trace-depths)]
                [prefix (spaces depth)])
           (parameterize ([trace-depths (+ depth 1)])
             (printf "~A~S ...~%" prefix `(,'name ,@args))
             (call-with-values
              (thunk (apply function args))
              (λ results
                (printf "~A-> ~S~%" prefix results)
               (apply values results)))))))]))
```

Stash this in a file called `define-traced.rkt` and then `require` it, and tell it to trace the procedures you care about:

```
#lang racket

(require "define-traced.rkt")

(define (square x) (* x x))
(define (average x y) (/ (+ x y) 2))
(define/traced (improve guess x) (average guess (/ x guess)))
(define (good-enough? guess x) (< (abs (- (square guess) x)) 0.001 ))
(define/traced (sqrt-iter guess x) (if (good-enough? guess x) guess (sqrt-iter (improve guess x) x)))
(define (sqrt x) (sqrt-iter 1.0 x))
(sqrt 2)
```

Which will duly print this:

```
(sqrt-iter 1.0 2) ...
 (improve 1.0 2) ...
 -> (1.5)
 (sqrt-iter 1.5 2) ...
  (improve 1.5 2) ...
  -> (1.4166666666666665)
  (sqrt-iter 1.4166666666666665 2) ...
   (improve 1.4166666666666665 2) ...
   -> (1.4142156862745097)
   (sqrt-iter 1.4142156862745097 2) ...
   -> (1.4142156862745097)
  -> (1.4142156862745097)
 -> (1.4142156862745097)
-> (1.4142156862745097)
1.4142156862745097
```

Note that when I said it was a *rudimentary* facility I meant it: in particular it will probably turn tail calls into non-tail calls, and there are many other things wrong with it.  But it took less long to write than it would take to read the manual on some hairy facility.  If I was going to use this thing just once (and this is probably the only time I will ever use it: it only made it into a file so I could require it in another file) it's worth it.  This is one of the glories of Lisp-family languages.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`begin`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/begin.html#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._begin%29%29) with [`printf`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._printf%29%29) (and also add one variable as counter):

```
#lang racket

(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(define (average x y)
  (/ (+ x y) 2))

(define (improve guess x)
  (average guess (/ x guess)))

(define (good-enough? guess x)
  (< (abs (- (square guess) x)) 0.001 ))

(define (sqrt-iter guess x count)
  (begin
    (printf "~a ~a \n" count guess)
    (if (good-enough? guess x)
        guess
        (sqrt-iter (improve guess x)
                   x
                   (+ 1 count)))))

(define (sqrt x) (sqrt-iter 1.0 x 1))
(sqrt 2)
```

```
1 1.0 
2 1.5 
3 1.4166666666666665 
4 1.4142156862745097

1.4142156862745097
```

Note that I used `#lang racket`- it seems that `sicp` don't have `print` or `printf`, but you can try [`write`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._write%29%29) or [`display`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._display%29%29) to achieve similar result.

Comment: you can drop `begin` and the program is identical. the body of a `define` procedure already supports evaluating multiple expressions and implicitly returns the last one.

Answer (score 1):

@ignis provides the proper technique for this. However, before you dive into the deep ocean of `define-syntax`, maybe you want the quick-and-dirty approach -

```scm
#lang sicp

(define (sqrt-iter guess x)
  (for-each display (list "sqrt-iter" " " guess " " x "\n"))
  (if (good-enough? guess x)
      guess
      (sqrt-iter (improve guess x) x)))

(sqrt 2)
```

```
sqrt-iter 1.0 2
sqrt-iter 1.5 2
sqrt-iter 1.4166666666666665 2
sqrt-iter 1.4142156862745097 2
1.4142156862745097
```